# How to grant executables permission to run without causing Microsoft Security Essentials to melt down?

Tags: windows-xp, ms-security-essentials

Practically every time I run MinGW gcc, my anti-virus program (MS security essentials, specifically msmpeng.exe) goes berserk, and steals 100% of the CPU for several seconds. This is maddening when I'm just compiling a few hundred lines of code, and the actual compile only takes mere milliseconds, once msmpeng decides to stand down.

I've tried adding gcc.exe to the excluded processes in the Settings tab of the Security Essentials interface, and the entire MinGW/bin to the excluded files/locations, but this clearly doesn't convince msmpeng that gcc is harmless. So how is one *supposed to* grant an executable the right to run w/o incurring msmpeng?

Comment: I've noticed that when the compile fails, it fails almost instantly. It's only when the compile succeeds that msmpeng locks up for 10 straight seconds. Suspicion is that it's the appearance of a new .exe file, seemingly from nowhere, that trips msmpeng.

Comment: question would be offtopic @ [programmers.se]

Comment: @sathya - ok, np. never quite sure the breakdown between SO, programmers, and superuser.

Comment: SO == programming questions, SU == questions on software & hardware, programmers.. actually I'm not familiar with programmers' manifesto

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps when your code is compiling it writes to a temporary directory, have a look under the real time protection tab in your settings using the mssecs gui. The way I understand it is that MsMpEng is scanning read and written data regardless of what program is trying to write the data.
Hope this helps.